# Sqlite ignore database constraints in unti test

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, phpunit

I am trying to test that a certain model in my database can (or cannot) be deleted based on some related models / database constraints.

I'm using SQLite in my Laravel Unit test, but it seems like it is ignoring the constraints and always allows the deletion to occur without error in the test when I have factoried up related models that don't get deleted first.

Is this just an sqlite thing or is there some setting I'm not aware about?

Here is a simple version of my test

```
/** @test */
public function product_canot_be_deleted()
{
    $product = factory(Product::class)->create([
        'deletion_flag' => 1
    ]);
    factory(Service::class)->create([
        'product_id' => $product->id
    ]);

    $this->artisan('products:delete');

    $this->assertCount(1, Product::all());
    $this->assertCount(1, Service::all());
}
```

the command just loops through all products in the table, that have been flagged for deletion.
This test fails and allows the product to be deleted.
The product should not be able to deleted while it has an associated service.  the relevant lines services migration file looks like this

```
$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
```

No mention on cascading deletes.

Comment: Foreign key constraints are disabled by default in sqlite, see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable). Which laravel version are you using? It was added in laravel 5.7, see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26298).

Comment: I'm on 6.0.  OK, how I do add that `foreign_key_constraints ` setting?  Seems like exactly what I need.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#configuration) you can add the `DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=true` environment variable, something like `<env name="DB_FOREIGN_KEYS" value="true"/>` in your `phpunit.xml` file.

Comment: OK, figured it out.  In my PHPUnit.xml I had this line.  `<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>` so In the `database.php` config file I added this line into the `testing` block: `'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),` which now works perfectly.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JohnHalsey: Consider to add yours as an answer. This is much more visible and you can also elaborate a bit on it, code examples / snippets etc. This works best for Stackoverflow. And you can even accept your own answer after a bit of time. Just saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are disabled by default in sqlite.

From the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable):

> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
>   compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database
>   connection. (Note, however, that future releases of SQLite might
>   change so that foreign key constraints enabled by default. Careful
>   developers will not make any assumptions about whether or not foreign
>   keys are enabled by default but will instead enable or disable them as
>   necessary.)

In [5.7](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26298) a config option to enable foreign keys was added to Laravel, so you can do the following:

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#configuration)

> To enable foreign key constraints for SQLite connections, you should
>   set the DB_FOREIGN_KEYS environment variable to true:

```
DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=true
```

Or you can add the `foreign_key_constraints` to your database configuration:

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#configuration)

> To enable foreign key constraints for SQLite connections, you should
>   add the foreign_key_constraints option to your config/database.php
>   configuration file:

```
'sqlite' => [
    // ...
    'foreign_key_constraints' => true,
],
```